# Common way of describing the fact that one topic overlaps with another one

Tags: phrase-request

What's the most common way of describing the fact that the subject matter being talked is overlapping with some other area?

Precisely, what would you say below instead of "bridging on"?

> -- Why didn't Jack agree to pave this road with asphalt last Friday?
>
> -- It's a complicated matter **bridging on** Jack's religious views. Firstly, he can't stand the smell of warm asphalt as it brings back
>   his memories of the negative experience he once had at a construction
>   site when one of his classmates got stuck in warm asphalt and almost
>   died. Another reason is because he considers Friday to be a holy day
>   reserved only for prayer and fasting, but not for work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word **involving**.  **involve** is about as common as a word can get for that kind of context.

> Jack refused to pave this road with asphalt last Friday for reasons involving [or "for reasons that involve"] his religious views.

P.S. I see no "bridge" between the two ideas in your example, the childhood experience and the religious views.  "To bridge on" suggests a relationship between the two; you can get from the one to the other.

Comment: I see in your example that you've added "for reasons", hence, I need to ask you: would "involving" fit in well in my first example instead of "bringing on"? In other words, does "It's a complicated matter involving Jack's religious views" sound fine?

Comment: Yes, "a complicated matter involving Jack's religious views" is fine.